# Segmentation Fault with opencv on reading a video from a file

Tags: c++, c, opencv, segmentation-fault

i am running a simple code to capture a video from a file but its return a segmentation fault

```
     #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
     #include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
     #include <stdio.h>
     //#include <iostream>

     using namespace cv;
     using namespace std;

     int main()
     {
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("/home/ayush/20130521053652.avi");

    IplImage* frame = NULL;

    if(!capture)
    {
        printf("Video Not Opened\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int width = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int height = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int frame_count = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,  CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    printf("Video Size = %d x %d\n",width,height);
    printf("FPS = %f\nTotal Frames = %d\n",fps,frame_count);

    while(1)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        if(!frame)
        {
            printf("Capture Finished\n");
            break;
        }

        cvShowImage("video",frame);
        cvWaitKey(10);
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;
}
```

i am also tried this above code which is actually a solution for a particular question but its still giving me a same thing...

Video file information

```
   $file 20130521053652.avi 
   20130521053652.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 480, 30.00 fps, video:
```

some more information

```
   Dimensions: 640 x 480
   Codec:      24-bit RGB
   Framerate:  30 frames per second
   Bitrate:    N/A
```

i think there must be issue with codec my platform is linux/ubuntu 12.04 LTS please can any body suggest me solution for this

Through gdb debugger the Segmentation fault is giving at `frame = cvQueryFrame(capture)`

o/p is something this

```
     (gdb) 
      66          frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);           
     (gdb) 

                  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
                __memcpy_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S:160
       160  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S: No such file or directory.
```

through Qt IDE ==> Debugging

```
      0xb751d9fa  <+0x146a>         movzbl (%eax),%eax
      1951  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S
      0xb751d9fd  <+0x146d>         mov    %al,(%edx)
      1952  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S
      1953  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S
      0xb751d9ff  <+0x146f>         mov    0x8(%esp),%eax
      1954  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S
      1955  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S
      1956  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S
      1957  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S
      1958  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S
      1959  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S
      0xb751da03  <+0x1473>         pop    %ebx
      0xb751da04  <+0x1474
```

Comment: Run in a debugger. It will stop when the crash happens, and will then let you examine the call stack as well as let you print values of variables.

Comment: through gdb the error is due to `frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);`

Comment: is this any problem related to video `codec`.......

Comment: I'm getting the same problem here, but with the OpenCV read() function of VideoCapture! However, I only have the problem when working with 640x480 resolution video. Don't have this problem with lower resolutions...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in OpenCV 2.4, using cvCaptureFromFile()/cvQueryFrame().  Converting my AVI to an FLV (using avconv) worked for me.

My guess is that this is an OpenCV bug.

Comment: Oh it really did help? maybe I will try converting my videos to FLV and hopefully they can work!